# What is the difference between these two ways of declaring an array?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between:

```
int [][] myArray;
```

and

```
int [,] myOtherArray;
```

Comment: Note that mixing the two techniques -- making a ragged array of multidimensional arrays -- is legal but almost certainly a bad idea. It makes the code hard to read. See my article on the subject for details. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays.aspx

Answer (score 21):

The first is a jagged array: an array where each item in the array is another array

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];
jaggedArray[0] = new int[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new int[4];
jaggedArray[2] = new int[2];
```

The second is a multidimensional array, aka a matrix.

```
int[,] array = new int[4, 2]; // create a 4 by 2 matrix
```

Answer (score 17):

`myArray` is a [*jagged* array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx), or an array of arrays. Each element of `myArray` is itself an `int[]`.

`myOtherArray` is a [*rectangular* (or *multidimensional*) array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) - a single object containing all the data directly.

Which you should use really depends on the situation. Sometimes it can be handy to have an array for each "row" of data (with the ability to replace whole rows, and have rows with different lengths), whereas at other times it makes sense to force a uniform layout.

Comment: can you please either elaborate on or provide resources regarding where which use is more appropriate?

Comment: @smartcaveman: Not easily, I'm afraid. There will be pros and cons which are very situation-specific. If you give me a particular situation I could give some thoughts though.

Answer (score 9):

I found the best way to understand it was to see a graphical representation of it =)

```
int[][] jagged = new int[3][];
jagged[0] = new int[1];
jagged[1] = new int[2];
jagged[2] = new int[4];
```

will look like this

```
[0] - [0]
[1] - [0][1]
[2] - [0][1][2][3]
```

while a two+ dimensional

```
int[,] twodimensional = new int[3,4]
```

will look like this

```
[0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3]
[1,0][1,1][1,2][1,3]
[2,0][2,1][2,2][2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

The first is a jagged array, the other multi-dimensional - the difference is that the elements of a jagged array can be of different dimensions and sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Jagged array:

```
int [][] myArray;
```

Rectangular array:

```
int [,] myOtherArray;
```

Quote [Comparing Rectangular and Jagged Arrays](http://en.csharp-online.net/All_about_Arrays_in_CSharp%E2%80%94Comparing_Rectangular_and_Jagged_Arrays) :

> The structure of rectangular and
>   jagged arrays is significantly
>   different.
>
> One-dimensional arrays have specific
>   instructions in the CIL that allow
>   them to be optimized for performance.
>   Rectangular arrays do not have these
>   instructions, and are not optimized to
>   the same level. Because of this, it
>   can sometimes be more efficient to use
>   jagged arrays of one-dimensional
>   arrays—which can be optimized—than
>   rectangular arrays, which cannot. On
>   the other hand, the programming
>   complexity can be less for a
>   rectangular array because it can be
>   treated as a single unit, rather than
>   an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a duplicate.  One is a jagged array, one is a two-dimensional array.  You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements declare uninitialized multi-dimensional arrays of ints. The first is a jagged array and the second is 2-dimensional.

You can initialize the 2-dimensional array at the same time as you declare it as follows:

`int[,] array4 = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };`

OR,

`int[,] array = new int[4, 2];`

Refer to the official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):